# Website with permament error for software testing

Tags: unit-testing, http-status-codes

Which websites provide typical errors and http status codes on demand to test software?

I think of something like `http://err404.example.com/` resulting `Error 404`. 
This could be quite handy to create test cases for test driven development of a download tool.

Comment: Best practice is to mock http requests. Your test should be able to run offline.

Comment: Agreed. There are plenty of sites that do you you "want". But using them will make your tests slow and unreliable. There is no upside.  Your library can be trusted to return status codes, so you can mock on top of that. (Never write your own HTTP parsing library.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tools available to do this as part of your local development cycle, e.g. [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/).

The benefit you'll get from this is that it's now under **your** control and not somebody elses